# Reading and Editing metadata of mp3 in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, metadata, mp3

So, My client requested an electron app which can update metadata of mp3 files. What are the ways I can read and write Id3-v2.4 metadata tags of a mp3. I used `node-id3` npm library but it clears **GEOB** data of the mp3 file which are really important to the client. What are the solutions?